# How to write F# stm as >>= pipeline

Tags: haskell, f#, stm

Can somebody please explain how to write this FSharpx stm as a pipeline?

```
    stm {
        let! allTops = readTVar tAllTops
        let! thisPlayerTops = mapM removeOtherPlayersScores allTops
        let! markedTops = mapM markAsNonEmpty thisPlayerTops

        return 
            markedTops 
            |> Seq.filter fst 
            |> Seq.map snd
            |> List.ofSeq
    }
```

I'm thinking of haskell-like >>= pipelines.

Thanks!

UPDATE:
A little bit of clarification in order to avoid the confusion:

I was thinking that one should be able to define the >>= operator in F# in terms of stm.Bind and stm.Return. I tried to do that myself by I got lost.

UPDATE2:
After Thomas' answer I post the updated version which I think it looks pretty OK.  If I understand correctly, because of lack of type-classes the operator >>= doesn't have the same power as in Haskell.

I agree that it's not idiomatic for F# but it's probably a good exercise.

```
    readTVar tAllTops
    >>= mapM removeOtherPlayersScores 
    >>= mapM markAsNonEmpty 
    >>= stm.Return >> Seq.filter fst  >> Seq.map snd >> List.ofSeq
    |> atomically
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `>>=` operator in Haskell is just a symbolic name for the *bind* operation, so you can define it in F# just as an alias for `stm.Bind`:

```
let (>>=) v f = stm.Bind(v, f)
```

Using the operator, you could rewrite the code as follows:

```
readTVar tAllTops >>= fun allTops ->
removeOtherPlayersScores allTops >>= fun thisPlayerTops ->
mapM markAsNonEmpty thisPlayerTops >>= fun markedTops ->
  markedTops 
  |> Seq.filter fst 
  |> Seq.map snd
  |> List.ofSeq
  |> stm.Return
```

This is certainly an interesting thing and a good way to learn about monads in F# (especially if you are coming from the Haskell background), but it is not an idiomatic style - the idiomatic style in F# is to use the computations explicitly.

One limitation of this approach (compared to Haskell) is that `>>=` is not polymorphic over monads, so you're not gaining anything. Also, I think that there is a general consensus that using the computation blocks is more readable (for F# developers)

Comment: I wasn't sure how was I supposed to read stm.Bind type. I added an updated solution based on your operator >>= Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The main difference that an STM expression is converted to IO using `atomically` in Haskell, the difference syntax for binding monadic results (aka computation expressions) to names (using the `<-` operator) and that Haskell lists are lazy by default, which means that you don't need to use the `Seq` library (which, as far as I know, gives you lazy lists in F#).

```
atomically $ do
  allTops <- readTVar tAllTops
  thisPlayerTops <- mapM removeOtherPlayersScores allTops
  markedTops <- mapM markAsNonEmpty thisPlayerTops
  return (map snd . filter fst $ markedTops)
```

Comment: I understand this is the equivalent haskell code but what I would like to have is the F# code equivalent to my original stm. I was thinking that one should be able to define the >>= operator in F# in terms of stm.Bind and stm.Return. I tried to do that myself by I got lost.

Comment: Oh, sorry - I totally misinterpreted the question!